# Filter documents with a property that can be or true or null MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this query:

```
collection.aggregate([
    { $match:{ "card.discovery": true } }
    { $sample: { size: 4 } }
]);
```

And it works because I need to get 4 random entries from that collection, but `card.discovery` can be `true` or `null`, and this obviously only returning documents with `card.discovery` set to `true`.

How can I filter the documents so that `card.discovery` can be or `true` or `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```
{ $match: { "card.discovery": { $in: [ true, null ] } } }
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KGIY2v7fTY2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$in` operator:

```
collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { "card.discovery": { $in: [null, true] } } },
    { $sample: { size: 4 } }
]);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `$or` operator:

```
collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { $or: ["{card.discovery": true }, {"card.discovery": null}] } },
    { $sample: { size: 4 } }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `$or` option

collection

```
[{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "card" : {
        "discovery" : true
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : 2.0, 
    "card" : {
        "discovery" : null
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : 3.0, 
    "card" : {
        "discovery" : true
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : 4.0, 
    "card" : {
        "discovery" : true
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : 5.0, 
    "card" : {
        "discovery" : null
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : 6.0, 
    "card" : {
        "discovery" : false
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : 7.0, 
    "card" : {
        "discovery" : false
    }
}]
```

Query

```
db1.aggregate([
        { $match: { $or: [{ "card.discovery": true }, { "card.discovery": null }] }, },
        { $sample: { size: 4 } }
    ]).toArray();
```

Output

```
[
        {
            "_id": 4,
            "card": {
                "discovery": true
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "card": {
                "discovery": true
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "card": {
                "discovery": true
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": 5,
            "card": {
                "discovery": null
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```